# put multiple matches on one line to a new line using grep

Tags: command-line, grep

I need to put multiple matches on a line each on a new line

example:

```bash
grep "banana"


This is the output
```

Apple `banana` orange `banana` lemon

melon `banana`

grapes apple `banana`

```
I want to become:
```

Apple `banana` orange

`banana` lemon

melon `banana`

grapes apple `banana`

I want to put all until the next match on a line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```bash
sed 's/\(.*banana.*\)\(banana.*\)/\1\n\2/' file
```

Comment: What if we are expecting more than two matches per line?

Comment: @ManojKumar: I suggest to start a new question.

Comment: here it is http://askubuntu.com/questions/862793/repeat-whole-line-matches-with-grep-for-multiple-instances-on-the-same-line