# Repeat whole line matches with grep for multiple instances on the same line

Tags: text-processing, grep, multiple-instances

An offshoot from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/573003/put-multiple-matches-on-one-line-to-a-new-line-using-grep/573048?noredirect=1#comment1331560_573048) question:

While searching for the string "banana" from the following file, we would like 1,2,3 and 7 instances of lines 1,2,3 and 4 respectively. The number of grep outputs should equal the number of match instances while still returning the entire line.

```
There is one banana here
There are two banana banana here
There are three banana banana banana here
Basically there is no limit to how many banana banana banana banana banana banana banana we can have
In fact we need not have any too!
```

Note: If we remove the restriction of whole lines in the output, we have:

```
grep -no "banana" tempfile
```

which returns

```
1:banana
2:banana
2:banana
3:banana
3:banana
3:banana
4:banana
4:banana
4:banana
4:banana
4:banana
4:banana
4:banana
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: This is the intended output

```
1 There is one banana here
2 There are two banana banana here
2 There are two banana banana here
3 There are three banana banana banana here
3 There are three banana banana banana here
3 There are three banana banana banana here
4 Basically there is no limit to how many banana banana banana banana banana banana banana we can have
4 Basically there is no limit to how many banana banana banana banana banana banana banana we can have
4 Basically there is no limit to how many banana banana banana banana banana banana banana we can have
4 Basically there is no limit to how many banana banana banana banana banana banana banana we can have
4 Basically there is no limit to how many banana banana banana banana banana banana banana we can have
4 Basically there is no limit to how many banana banana banana banana banana banana banana we can have
4 Basically there is no limit to how many banana banana banana banana banana banana banana we can have
```

Comment: Does it have to be `grep`? I can think of a way to do it in `perl`...

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "repeat the whole line match" and maybe provide an example of what you expect output to be ?  You want `There are two banana banana here` to be printed 2 times because there's 2 matches ?

Comment: Is this what you wanted ? http://paste.ubuntu.com/23660761/

Comment: @Serg Yes, that's exactly what I wanted.. Sorry for not being clear. I am editing my question now

Comment: @ManojKumar In that case, please take time to mark one of the answers as accepted that provides the best solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` doesn't have counter for matches, only `-c` counter for lines that have the match, but we can use `awk` to do that. As far as I understand , you want to print the line that matches x number of times based on the amount of matches. Well, here it is:

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i=="banana") counter++;for(j=1;j<=counter;j++) print NR,$0;counter=0 }' input.txt         
1 There is one banana here
2 There are two banana banana here
2 There are two banana banana here
3 There are three banana banana banana here
3 There are three banana banana banana here
3 There are three banana banana banana here
4 Basically there is no limit to how many banana banana banana banana banana banana banana we can have
4 Basically there is no limit to how many banana banana banana banana banana banana banana we can have
4 Basically there is no limit to how many banana banana banana banana banana banana banana we can have
4 Basically there is no limit to how many banana banana banana banana banana banana banana we can have
4 Basically there is no limit to how many banana banana banana banana banana banana banana we can have
4 Basically there is no limit to how many banana banana banana banana banana banana banana we can have
4 Basically there is no limit to how many banana banana banana banana banana banana banana we can have
```

Basic idea here is that we loop over each word in a line, and count matches. If there's a match we increment counter and then use that counter to print the same line in a loop. Finally counter is reset and process repeats

Comment: This does not repeat the lines, as asked by OP.

Comment: @AdrienBeau I've edited my answer, please see the changes, but so far OP hasn't been clear on what exactly they want as output, so I'll trust your comment that OP wants lines repeated.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `perl` string repetition operator, obtaining the number of repeats by evaluating the result of the match in a scalar context:

```
$ perl -pe '$_ x= (() = /banana/g)' file
There is one banana here
There are two banana banana here
There are two banana banana here
There are three banana banana banana here
There are three banana banana banana here
There are three banana banana banana here
Basically there is no limit to how many banana banana banana banana banana banana banana we can have
Basically there is no limit to how many banana banana banana banana banana banana banana we can have
Basically there is no limit to how many banana banana banana banana banana banana banana we can have
Basically there is no limit to how many banana banana banana banana banana banana banana we can have
Basically there is no limit to how many banana banana banana banana banana banana banana we can have
Basically there is no limit to how many banana banana banana banana banana banana banana we can have
Basically there is no limit to how many banana banana banana banana banana banana banana we can have
```

Comment: Thanks! But I am accepting the answer by @Serg because it is easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Its not very pretty, but you could use something like

```
awk '{print NR, gsub(/banana/, "")' <tempfile
```

It works by using the `awk` `gsub` command to substitute the match pattern (here, banana) and it returns the number of times that it performs the substitution. If then outputs the the input line number and the number of matches

Or to repeat the input line multiple times

```
awk '{A=$0
b=gsub(/banana/, "")
for (i=1; i<=b; i++) print A
}' <tempfile
```